# Display from multiple data sources

Tags: website-design, web-app, javascript

I am building a data grid presenting table-structured data (columns and rows) to end users. This grid contains about 500 records but of these records only 350 are distinct on some required fields.

I will like suggestions on how to visually present this data (still in grid format) to end users grouping similar records together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to group these results, but this will depend on what fields you allow grouping. Once you decide (or programmatically allow the user to pick which column they should by group by) you can take your pick on hierarchical table layouts:

- Expandable
- Modular (blocks)
- Drill-down strategy

For more ideas on hierarchical tabular display, search accordingly.